# Url Rewrite not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Url pointing to the project: `http://localhost/project5/public/index.php`

I want to rewrite the url and make it look like this `http://localhost/project5/index.php`

Directory Structure

```
project5
│ 
├───includes
├───public
│   │───css
│   │───js
│   │───img
│   │───index.php
│   └───residential-for-sale.php
├───logs
```

.htaccess code which i am using to hide .php extension and to make "public" as my working directory and to remove "public" from the url:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

# hide .php Extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# to hide public directory
RewriteRule ^project5/((?!public/).*)$ project5/public/$1 [L]
```

When i try to access the `http://localhost/project5/index.php` it throws me Error 404: page not found

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

# hide .php Extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# to hide public directory
RewriteRule ^project5/((?!public/).*)$ project5/public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: its not working....it throws me Error 403...you dont have permission o access this page

Comment: My code doesn't have anything related to 403 here. Is that something in your earlier code?

Comment: when i use http://localhost/project5/ (it throws me 403)
& when i use http://localhost/project5/index (it throws me 404)

i am struggling with this

Comment: OK can you post your latest .htaccess in your question for further investigation.